# Regex to get specific part of a string in a match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

In the source of a file I have several 'hooks' which I want to get in order to apply some extra variables from my PHP-script.
The hooks are applied to the source like: @include_plugin PluginName@

I am able to find them using `preg_match_all('/@include_plugin .*@/', $sSource, $aPlugins);`
This regex is giving me the matches I want, but is it also possible to directly get `PluginName` instead of my solution and then having to apply a substring to the match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a capturing group in your regular expression. These are created by placing parenthesis around part of the pattern.

So we change your `.*` into `(.*)`

```
preg_match_all('/@include_plugin (.*)@/', $sSource, $aPlugins);
var_dump($aPlugins);
```

Check the output from the var dump, there will be a new sub-array at index 1 with the plugin names only.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "@include_plugin PluginName@"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "PluginName"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I'm looking for. +1 accepted (in 10 mins, due too accepttime restriction ;)).